# Accordion sub menu and content slide

Tags: jquery, accordion

Hope someone can quickly help me.

Please see here - http://www.designbyaltitude.com/test

As you can see the content slides upwards once you click on a link on the sidebar.

However what I also want is a submenu to dropdown when the blue bar is clicked.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

my first idea is to add additional classes to parent node and if the hey submenus display while the parent has class?!

that should be easy to realize.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about what you wanna do but i'll still try to help you. From what i understand, you want to get a submenu (maybe in slideDown?) when you click on the blue bar.  I guess this submenu is linked to the loaded content (the section).  I suggest you put the submenuS in a div (position: relative) all on the same level. All submenu should we in an UL (or a div, whatever) setted in position: absolute (the container will be absolute position withing the relative div).  All UL should we placed top:0 left:0 (or whatever the coords as long as all containers are stacked).  Then, in the "" link of the blue bar, you add an attribute HREF of "#the_wanted_submenu" and on click slideDown the concerned elements and hide all others.

```
$('#blueBar a').click(function() {
   $($(this).attr('href')).siblings().slideUp(); //Hide all submenus but the current
   $($(this).attr('href')).slideDown(); // Show wanted submenu
});
```